# Error using Angular with PHP

Tags: php, angularjs

I guess, I got something wrong in this code. Any idea what I got wrong with it ?

```
    * Popup alert notification using Growl Notifications */

function growl_based_notification()
{
    global $context;

if (!empty($context['user']['mentions']))

    // Say they have unread alerts.


    $html = '<body ng-app="af_notify" ng-controller="growlCtrl">

    <growl-notifications></growl-notifications>
    <growl-notification>
      Psst ! You have unread notifications
    </growl-notification>
  </body>';
    return $html;


}
```

I am using the above in a php template which need to display the output of an ng-app

Comment: `something wrong` doesn't tell us anything about what is happening in browser

Comment: Do you understand PHP at all ? Anything wrong with the code means the same. I am not good at php and I have to write php code. My AngularJS is correct but the code is not working even after added to php template.

Comment: But that isn't a proper problem description. Where is the function called? Is there an `echo` anywhere for this? Does the html make it to the browser? You have not given us very much information to work from and we can't read minds

Comment: Read the line below code. I have tagged this Angular + PHP

Comment: Am familiar with both .... please learn how to define problems .... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Your history of asking here hasn't been very successful. Good questions with proper problem statements will typically get good answers and fast

Comment: My dear, I clearly said, 1. Display output of ng-app, 2. Using inside a php template. Obviously my point 1 is failing. I am using in php, so it is not working. ie, not displayed. Instead of teaching others, you could have asked what error you are getting.

Comment: Stop playing games...look at all the questions you have asked. You get the same issue constantly...not explaining the actual problem and when asked for clarification you dodge direct answers. I did ask questions and you failed to respond. It's not us needing the help.

Comment: Some people with ego voted me down. Look down, I got the problem zeroed in. If you do not know coding, please do not accuse others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks you've got one of these in your project: [Angular Growl Notifications](https://github.com/jvandemo/angular-growl-notifications) or [Easy notifications in AngularJs applications](http://code.ciphertrick.com/2015/04/05/easy-notifications-in-angularjs-applications/)

If you are using the first one (my best bet), try adding all notifications

```
<growl-notification> ... </growl-notification>
```

**inside** the "plural" directive:

```
<growl-notifications> add them here </growl-notification>
```

Like this:

```
<growl-notifications>

    <growl-notification>
        Psst ! You have unread notifications
    </growl-notification>

    <growl-notification>
        Another notification
    </growl-notification>

</growl-notification>
```

[Here](http://jvandemo.github.io/angular-growl-notifications/docs/directives/growl-notifications) you can read this "plural" one is needed to indicate the place all individual notifications are to be rendered (inserted).

#### Added:

Without more code to look at (who is calling what function with what parameters and values), I'd suggest you to make this TEST (not definitive, of course):

comment this line:

```
 if (!empty($context['user']['mentions']))
```

like this:

```
 //if (!empty($context['user']['mentions'])) {
```

By the way, you should have an opening bracket (at the end of this "if" line) and another closing bracket at the end (after "return $html;", two "}" instead of only one), though that may be a different point.

Let us know if you get notifications with that "if" line temporarily not affecting (i.e., whatever there is in $context, the new $html is returned). If this is the case, then the problem is in giving value to your $context.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am using Growl notifications. I will try and update.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. Still, no output.

Comment: Will try and update. Thanks again.

Comment: You are very correct. When removed function and simply used echo, it worked. I guess I need to check the array. Many thanks. :thumbsup: